# iPhone Alarm App mysterious inactivation (UILocalNotification)

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, alarm

I am in the final stages of development for an iPhone Alarm App

The alarm works through notification centre.

Work well for short time delays (say 2 hours)

Does not work in the morning (Long time delay 8 hours)

Also it seems to work fine on phones that do not have internet access?

Could there be some kind of automatic time updating/syncing that is disturbing alarm function?

Is the 8 hour+ time delayed neutralising the notificaiton?

Does the app need to be in the foreground?

So the alarm works for short time delays, but not in the morning (When it is meant to!)

We are due to submit update to Apple very soon!

Thank you Kindly,

Henry (Aus.)

```
-(void)addLocalNotification:(myAlarmData *)ma WeekDay:(int)mweekday
{
    UILocalNotification *noti = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

    NSDateComponents *dcom = [gregorian components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit |NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:now];

    [dcom setWeekday:mweekday];
    [dcom setHour:ma.mHour];
    [dcom setMinute:ma.mMinute];
    [dcom setSecond:0];


    NSDate *fireDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:dcom];

    noti.fireDate = fireDate;
    noti.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    noti.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wake up %@!", [GlobalData gSettings].name];
    noti.soundName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.caf", ma.soundName];
    noti.alertAction = @"OK";

    noti.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;

    noti.userInfo = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      ma.mid, @"mid",
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", mweekday], @"day",
                      ma.soundName, @"sound",
                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ma.snooze], @"snooze",
                      ma.title, @"title",
                      @"Close", @"action",
                      @"real", @"more",
                      nil] autorelease];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:noti];

    [noti release];
    [gregorian release];
}
```

Comment: How many notifications are you scheduling? If you try to schedule more than 64 notifications, `-scheduleLocalNotification:` will simply do nothing at all.

Comment: thanks for you reply. No there are not nearly that many notifications.

Comment: we did another test and found that if the alarm is set for greater than 8 hours the alarm does not activate. thanks